# presentViewController shows empty View

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have been trying to present a view controller on my app but whenever I present it, it gives me an empty view. I have searched a lot on the internet and the StackOverFlow but none of the solutions are working for me. Here is my code:
In my `viewWillAppear`, I am calling the method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentConfirmationView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
```

and here is the definition to the `presentConfirmationView`:

```
ConfirmRegistrationViewController *confirmationRegistrationController = [[ConfirmRegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfirmRegistrationViewController" bundle:Nil];
[self presentViewController:confirmationRegistrationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Any idea why this might be happening? BTW, I am using Xcode 5.0.2.
I have tried to shift the code to `viewDidAppear` as well but to no avail.

Comment: Try in `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: Been there, done that :(

Comment: Try calling function without scheduling it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! I have a story board, and I'm presenting a view using swift's presentViewController.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me (Xcode 6.4, iOS 8.4 simulator), the fix was to delete the app in the simulator and also delete my Build folder (I guess a Product->Clean command might also have worked).